# Stripe Contents not displaying on webpage (Blade)

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-blade

I am attempting to integrate the Stripe payment platform with my Laravel web-page. For some reason, the *card-element* div is not propagating with Stripe's elements. Here is a snipped of my body code:

```
<div class="checkout-section">
<div>
    <form action="#" method="POST" id="payment-form">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <h2>Billing Details</h2>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" value="{{ old('address') }}" required>
        </div>

        <div class="half-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="city">City</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" value="{{ old('city') }}" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="province">Province</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="province" name="province" value="{{ old('province') }}" required>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end half-form -->

        <div class="half-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="postalcode">Postal Code</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postalcode" name="postalcode" value="{{ old('postalcode') }}" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" required>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end half-form -->

        <div class="spacer"></div>

        <h2>Payment Details</h2>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name_on_card">Name on Card</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_on_card" name="name_on_card" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="card-element">
              Credit or debit card
            </label>
            <div id="card-element">
              <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
            </div>

            <!-- Used to display form errors -->
            <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>

        <button type="submit" id="complete-order" class="button-primary full-width">Complete Order</button>


    </form>
</div>
```

Toward the bottom of my code:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/">
(function(){
    // Create a Stripe client
    var stripe = Stripe({{config('stripe.key)}});

    // Create an instance of Elements
    var elements = stripe.elements();

    // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
    // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
    var style = {
      base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        lineHeight: '18px',
        fontFamily: '"Roboto", Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#aab7c4'
        }
      },
      invalid: {
        color: '#fa755a',
        iconColor: '#fa755a'
      }
    };

    // Create an instance of the card Element
    var card = elements.create('card', {
        style: style,
        hidePostalCode: true
    });

    // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
    card.mount('#card-element');

    // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
    card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      if (event.error) {
        displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
      } else {
        displayError.textContent = '';
      }
    });

    // Handle form submission
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      document.getElementById('complete-order').disabled = true;

      var options = {
        name: document.getElementById('name_on_card').value,
        address_line1: document.getElementById('address').value,
        address_city: document.getElementById('city').value,
        address_state: document.getElementById('province').value,
        address_zip: document.getElementById('postalcode').value
      }

      stripe.createToken(card, options).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
          // Inform the user if there was an error
          var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
          errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;

          // Enable the submit button
          document.getElementById('complete-order').disabled = false;
        } else {
          // Send the token to your server
          stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
        }
      });
    });

    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
      // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
      var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
      var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
      form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

      // Submit the form
      form.submit();
    }
})();
```

Chrome's developer tools -> console has nothing displayed in it.

[image: Preview of the website (img).]

Edit: I have confirmed that the key is being retrieved by dumping value.

Comment: I think your Stripe key should be quoted?  Have you checked the devtools console for errors?  BTW probably just how you named it but - `STRIPE_SECRET` should be your *publishable* key, **not** your *secret* key!

Comment: @Don'tPanic I fixed it to *STRIPE_KEY*. Blade is pulling that value from my .env file. I've also changed it to config('stripe.key') to match Laravel best practices. Still nothing in my devtools console.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I understand what you meant... I needed quotes around the key... Thank you for pointing that out, that pretty much fixed my issue.

Comment: Glad you solved it.  As this was basically a typo, I suggest we close it as such.  BTW, if this code was live at any time, even just briefly, and your secret Stripe key was exposed, you should immediately rotate that key.